# Frame by frame video processing with ffmpeg pyspark and hadoop

Tags: hadoop, video, pyspark, hdfs

I would like to process mp4 video frames in parallel using spark and hadoop. I DO NOT want to extract all frames before processing. What I'm looking for is for a way to read frame data sequentially w.r.t. video time, then feed frames as they come to spark executors on a hadoop cluster using yarn. The mp4 video file can either be on the local filesystem or HDFS.

I can use ffmpeg to create a pipe, then read raw frame bytes (e.g., image = np.fromstring(pipe.stdout.read(1920*1080*3)
, dtype='uint8')). Is there any way to feed data (i.e., stream, as frames come in as a function of variable decoding time) to a spark RDD and have a map function that does something, e.g., compute average intensity?

I've been reading the spark docs for quite a bit of time and couldn't find anything that works in this scenario. I could be missing the forest for the trees. Please help if you can, even if it involves not using ffmpeg and a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, I have a working solution. While this may not work for everyone, it could possibly help some, so here goes:

I first created a script that extracts a frame from the video, this script has to exist on all worker nodes:

```
#!/home/hadoop/anaconda2/bin/python

import os
import sys
import subprocess as sp
import numpy as np
import cv2
import copy

# RDD.pipe sends via stdin
i = 0
try:
        i = input()
except:
    sys.exit()



file_name = 'v.mp4'
FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg" # on Linux ans Mac OS
command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
               '-i', '/home/hadoop/' + file_name,
               '-f', 'image2pipe',
               '-vf', 'select=gte(n\, %d)' % i,
               '-vframes', '1',
               '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
               '-loglevel', 'panic',
               '-vcodec', 'png', '-']
pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)
data = pipe.stdout.read()
pipe.stdout.close()
import base64
print(base64.b64encode(data))
```

Then, in a pyspark script, I create an RDD with script parameters:

```
params = [str(i)  for i in range(1, 1001)]
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(params, numSlices=1000)
pipeRDD = rdd1.pipe('/home/hadoop/src/extract_frame.sh')
resizedRDD = pipeRDD.map(resizeMapper)
test = resizedRDD.collect()
```

test now has the first 1000 frames. The resize mapper resizes each frame, here it is:

```
def resizeMapper(x):
    import base64
    import cv2
    a = base64.b64decode(x)
    im = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(a, dtype=np.uint8), 1)
    im = cv2.resize(im, (200, 200))
    return im
```

I hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: Hi Paul, have tried any other approach since your last message? Do you have an idea if this approach is as efficient as if you had first converted the mpeg file into a sequence file? Thanks.